# Не работает движение персонажа в 2d игре на tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр

У меня проблема с реализацией движения персонажа в 2d игре на tkinter. (Игру создавал по книге "Python для детей" Джейсон Р. Бриггс).
Персонаж стоит как вкопанный и не реагирует на управление.

Я знаю, что функция collided_left работает неправильно, она работает тогда, когда у персонажа нет никаких спрайтов поблизости. Щерез что параметр x всегда = 0. Почему эта функция не работает правильно?

```py
def within_y (co1,co2):
    return co1.y1 < co2.y1 < co1.y2 or co1.y1 < co2.y2 < co1.y2 
def collided_left (co1,co2):   
    if within_y(co1,co2) :
        if co2.x1 <= co1.x1 <= co2.x2 :
            return True
    return False
def collided_right (co1,co2):   
    if within_y(co1,co2) :
        if co1.x2 >= co2.x1 and co1.x2 <= co2.x2:
            return True
    return False
```

```
 if left and self.x < 0 and collided_left(co , sprite_co) :
                self.x = 0
                left = False
                print("ERROR")
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с координатами. Я допустил ошибку в написании переменной, как следствие следующие функции которые касались столкновений работали неправильно черз ложные координаты. Спасибо Bryan Oakley за помощь и то привел меня на мнение проверить функции со своими координатами.